# how to move the loader from left to right on hover?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, css-selectors

I have a simple div in which there is an  tag with 4 spans and a text
I am trying to create a loader on hovering my name.
The top line moves from left to right, after passing half way it get stucks in the middle and does not hides.
I am following a short youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ex7jGbyFgpA&t=156s

The code is also attached. Please help

```css
.name {
  // font-size: 6rem;
  margin: 0 0 3.5rem;
  color: #2196f3;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.2s;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.hi {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

a span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

a span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #2196f3);
}

a:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  left: 100px;
  `enter code here` transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href='#' className='name'>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span> Hafiz Arsam Rahmaan
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Pls, insert your css code with text, but not a picture.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov please check now

Answer (score 1):

Delete `margin: 0 0 3.5rem;`

Change `left: -10000%;` by `left: -100%;`

Check the demo below
(Don't forget to change class by className in your react component)

```css
a.name {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  color: #6600FF;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
a.name span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
a.name span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #2196f3)
}
a.name:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  left: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div>      
  <a href='#' class='name'> 
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    Hafiz Arsam Rahmaan
  </a>
</div>
```

**Demo with react**: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cwvu6e?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: this is not working in react. but it working here

Comment: It works with react, check my edit with react demo.